# IntelliJ + Spring Boot + GWT superDevMode

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, gwt, intellij-14

Anyone would have and example to make work a gwt project in superDevMode within IntelliJ.

I succeed in configuring maven to produce a standalone jar with the emmeded tomcat and the gwt compiled code (js files...).
The jar runs well. But I can't make the whole project work in devMode nor superDevMode into IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

I did a demo project. Check it out: https://github.com/feedm3/spring-boot-gwt

Comment: I've searched 2 days. this is the only solution works.

Comment: there's a little problem, after i import your demo project, the Idea's project web facet page, the web resource directory is empty, i have to set it manually, but after i set it manually idea prompt that facet 'Web' is imported from gradle, any changes made in it may be lost. how could i configure web facet in Gradle?